# Invalid Lookup Values Found Error

Tags: list, custom-list, lookup-column

I have a simple list with a non required lookup column.  If I try to create a new entry in the list with the lookup column left as "none", I receive the error:

> The list item could not be inserted or updated because invalid lookup values were found for the following field(s) in the list: [field]

A couple of notes:

- The lookup is on a calculated column.
- There is no error if the new row is created in datasheet view
- There is no error if a lookup value is selected

Here is the stack trace:

`[SPInvalidLookupValuesException: The list item could not be inserted or updated because invalid lookup values were found for the following field(s) in the list: [field].]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem(Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Int32& ulID, Object& objAttachmentNames, Object& objAttachmentContents, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion) +26873704
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion) +26873182
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Update() +166
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SaveButton.SaveItem(SPContext itemContext, Boolean uploadMode, String checkInComment) +20394338
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SaveButton.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +1325
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +70
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981`

Any thoughts?

Comment: What data type is your calculated column supposed to return?

Comment: It returns a 'single line of text'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SharePoint Foundation 2010, then this is a known issue where a custom list has a lookup field to another custom list that contains more than 20 items. If you set the value of the lookup field to "None," then you'll get the error. It looks like you'll need to apply an update to SharePoint to resolve the error. Here's more info:

1. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2687375
2. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/187bba01-98ee-4672-ba17-342309463c7a/list-item-could-not-be-updated-because-invalid-lookup-values-were-found-for-one-or-more-fields-in?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious
3. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/fc14a846-403c-4abb-85c6-af27a1dee159/nonrequired-lookup-column-throws-error-if-none-or-blank